# How to include javascript in PDF using Apache FOP

Tags: java, apache, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am using Apache FOP to create a PDF that contains a link to an external website. I would like to attach some javascript to the click event of this link. How do I go about including javascript in the resulting PDF (from within the xsl:fo)?

I have tried:

```
<fo:basic-link external-destination="javascript:app.alert('You clicked me.');">
    Click Me
</fo:basic-link>
```

Due to system constraints, I cannot inject the script into the PDF bytestream as was suggested here: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/xmlgraphics-fop-users/201102.mbox/%3C31016279.post@talk.nabble.com%3E

Comment: In order to do that with xsl fo, it would have to be an extension. RenderX has such extensions for PDF Forms as well as Javascript injection. Review the Apache web pages on extensions and see if one exists.